# Can a Polish citizen visiting USA drive to Canada and re-enter the US without any issues?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, paperwork, polish-citizens

Do they need any other documents, visas, etc?

Comment: Your rental car company must allow you to drive the car into Canada. Ask about this when you rent the car. Canada immigration officers _have_ been known to check rental car paperwork.

Answer (score 4):

[Polish citizens do not need a visa for Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas-result.asp?country=PL&result=2&message=0&standard=2&q3=).

[And since US visitor visas issued to Polish citizens are multiple-entry](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/fees/reciprocity-by-country/PL.html), you can be re-admitted to the US anytime if the visa's valid **or** if you stay in Canada for less than 30 days (even if the US visa is expired)

Comment: Or in most cases, even if the US visa has expired via Automatic Revalidation.  https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1218/~/automatic-revalidation-for-certain-temporary-visitors